# Does CloudFront path pattern need to exist as a directory in S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a a CloudFront Distribution with an S3 bucket as the origin (at its root).

If the origin has a path pattern of `test/*`, but I don't have a `test` directory in my S3 bucket, will requests such as `www.domain.com/test/t-shirt` fail?

I can't tell if that request would go to `bucket/test/t-shirt` or to `bucket/t-shirt`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `www.domain.com/test/t-shirt` will fail since the CloudFront tries to fetch the object stored in the S3 bucket `bucket` using the key `test/t-shirt`.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. That said, you may need to use [Lambda@Edge](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/edge/) to rewrite the request back to the S3 bucket to match up the CloudFront request with the S3 request.